# What is 'viewModel' in angularjs and how it works in order?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to know the order how it works when I define *state*.
I can explain seeing the code below

```
    $stateProvider.state("clients.index", {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: "/client/index",
        controller: "clientIndexController",
        resolve: {
            viewModel: ["clientService", function (clientService) {
                return clientService.getAllClients();
            }]
        }
    });
```

```
.factory("clientService", ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        getAllClients: function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/client/list',
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }
    }

}])
```

*resolve* is the promise that must occur before loading controller and templateURL. But what about the *viewModel*. Is that a reserved word? I go to *clientService* then get the list of clients then assign that list of clients to the *viewModel*?

Comment: `viewModel` is simply a property name. One can use any name. It would be wiser to use a more meaningful name like `allClients`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewModel` is simply a property name. One can use any name. It would be wiser to use a more meaningful name like `allClients`.

The `resolve` property of a router state is a map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected.

One can define more than one property for the `resolve` object:

```
$stateProvider.state("clients.index", {
    url: "",
    templateUrl: "/client/index",
    controller: "clientIndexController",
    resolve: {
        allClients: ["clientService", function (clientService) {
            return clientService.getAllClients();
        }],
        otherData: function(otherService) {
            return otherService.getOtherData();
        }
    }
});
```

In this case both services need to successfully return data before the router instantiates the controller and the template.